# Position text inside button vertically - reduce margin?

Tags: android, button, format

I am having trouble formatting the text inside my button. I have tried reducing the margins and padding and using gravity, but I still seem to have a some kind of margin around the text inside the button.
I have currently positioned the text in top, but as you see it stays very low and even goes out of the button.

Here is the code I use:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/counterValue"
android:layout_width="283dp"
android:layout_height="144dp"
android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:onClick="countIN"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:text="0"
android:textSize="140dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[As you see, the big 0 is at the very bottom of the box. I would like it to be right in the middle and with very small margins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFMJq.png)

Any ideas of what am I missing in my code?

Comment: Do not use "dp" for text size use "sp" instead. Can you paste a picture with the problem. this way people can answer you a lot faster.

Comment: adding  screen shot of your problem would be very helpful for us to give appropriate answer to your problem

Comment: Yes, sorry - I added the image now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the text size from "dp" to "sp" as in 140dp. If you want to keep this size tho, you might want to change the size for your button 
The line in problem is:

```
android:textSize="140dp"
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed "dp" to "sp", but nothing changes. Also - I need the text to be very huge, so 140sp is what I would really like to use. However, I can not make the size of the button bigger. Theoretically there is enough space - the button is 144dp and text is 140. Yes, the margin would be very small if centered, but thats exactly how I need it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Fell free to mark my answer so others with the same problem will get a chance to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the Button's height to `wrap_content`:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You can't have fixed height for the `Button` and fixed `textSize` and expect the text to be centered correctly.
**Edit**
Set this attribute:

```
android:includeFontPadding = "false"
```

Comment: If I use wrap_content, then the button becomes way bigger than I need it to be.

Comment: Then you need to change its textSize.

Comment: As I wrote - reducing text size is not what I need. I really need huge number on the button. Any idea how to reduce the margin on top of it?

Comment: Thanks - this is actually helpful. It took my text almost to the middle. Still a bit low, but much better.

Comment: This attribute removes any font padding, so the text is clear. If there is any space above or below you must adjust the height of the button or the size of the text.